# How to determine FFTW version?

Tags: c, libraries

The C library [FFTW ("Fastest Fourier Transform in the West")](https://www.fftw.org/) provides subroutines for calculating discrete Fourier transforms (DFTs).

How do I determine what version of FFTW I have on my Ubuntu installation?

Comment: Please try : For version 3.x : `dpkg -s libfftw3-3` , `dpkg -s [etc. separate packages]`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libfftw3-dev  ......... and version 2.x : `dpkg -s fftw2`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you’re interested in version 3 of the library,

```
dpkg -l 'libfftw3*'
```

will tell you which version and variant(s) of the library are currently installed on your system, and

```
apt search libfftw3
```

will tell you which are available for your system.

Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.04 have version 3.3.8, in single, double, long and quad precisions.